# AttributeError: module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'getWindowsWithTitle'

Tags: python, macos, pyautogui

I am writing a bot to interact with the browser (do not persuade me to rewrite for Selenium or Keyboard and others) and it gave me an error. There are no files with the name pyautogui nearby and I tried name it main and python v3.8, 3.9. Received this error in every case. MacOS

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rubicon/objc/ctypes_patch.py:21: UserWarning: rubicon.objc.ctypes_patch has only been tested with Python 3.4 through 3.8. You are using Python 3.9.4. Most likely things will work properly, but you may experience crashes if Python's internals have changed significantly.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alina/PycharmProjects/ABOBA/main_miner_alienworlds.py", line 183, in <module>
    for i in pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle('##### #######'):
AttributeError: module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'getWindowsWithTitle'
```

```
import pyautogui

…
for j in pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle('##### #######'):
    do something
```

pyautogui was installed with pip3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the wrong module!

https://pypi.org/project/PyGetWindow/ is the module containing `getWindowsWithTitle`

Comment: it raise this ImportError: cannot import name 'getWindowsWithTitle' from 'pygetwindow' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pygetwindow/__init__.py)

Comment: PyGetWindow also doesn't have that method on OSX only Windows - OP needs OSX

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately as of version 0.9.53, the pyautogui's windows feature only works on Windows, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKtcC.png from source below:-
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter20/

Comment: Hello there I am looking for pyautogui.getActiveWindowTitle for linux , is there any alternative. It will be of great help to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS users, you may need to use Quartz and AppKit instead.

In general, the AppKit is built-in, so you only need to install Quartz via:

```
pip install pyobjc
```

To get the window info:

```
import Quartz
from AppKit import NSWorkspace

# This function retrieves a list of all windows with their titles
def get_window_list():
    window_list = []
    window_info_list = Quartz.CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(Quartz.kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, Quartz.kCGNullWindowID)
    for window_info in window_info_list:
        window_list.append(window_info)
    return window_list

# This function will look for a window with a specific title
def get_window_with_title(title):
    for window in get_window_list():
        window_title = window.get('kCGWindowName', 'No Title')
        if window_title == title:
            return window
    return None

# Replace 'xxx' with the actual title of the window you're looking for
window_title = "xxx"
window = get_window_with_title(window_title)
print(window)
```

You will see the result like:

```
{
    kCGWindowAlpha = 1;
    kCGWindowBounds =     {
        Height = 851;
        Width = 515;
        X = 0;
        Y = 37;
    };
    kCGWindowIsOnscreen = 1;
    kCGWindowLayer = 0;
    kCGWindowMemoryUsage = 2160;
    kCGWindowName = xxx;
    kCGWindowNumber = 24901;
    kCGWindowOwnerName = xxx;
    kCGWindowOwnerPID = 41114;
    kCGWindowSharingState = 1;
    kCGWindowStoreType = 1;
}
```